# Flutter navigate to main screen instead of previous

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I just started working with Flutter and I'm not gonna lie its amazing. One "problem" I have encountered, though, is that when you hit the back key It will navigate to the previous screen. I know that thats what should happen, but how can I change that? Also, the appBar button does the same, so I'm looking for a "fix" for that one as well.

If you require any code, please, let me know! Have a great day, and sorry for any misspellings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    '/', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Create a named route '/' that corresponds to the main screen and done.
Any more queries feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set names for your routes in the `MaterialApp`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(),
        '/second': (context) => Page2(),
        '/third': (context) => Page3(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then you need to wrap the `Scaffold` of the third page (or any another page from which you want to navigate back to the `HomePage`) with a `WillPopScope` to change what happens when user presses the back button. Finally you need to use `popUntil` to navigate back to the `HomePage`.

This is the code for the `build` method of the third page:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/"));
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text('third page'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify "home" property in MaterialApp, there is no need to create any route. Navigation to homescreen can then be done as below:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```